# R - Extract CSV file from javascript link via RCurl

Tags: r, csv, web-scraping, rcurl

I have a url:

```
url <- "http://www.railroadpm.org/home/RPM/Performance%20Reports/BNSF.aspx"
```

that contains a link to a csv file that I would like to download. The "Export to CSV" link on the above page. The problem is that the csv file is not part of a url, but rather it's javascript.  What I would like to do is access the link and create a dataframe out of the csv file.  The javascript is:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl11$btnCSV','')
```

and from that I can tell that the id is

```
"ctl11_btnCSV"
```

but I am unsure of how this fits into RCUrl, which from SO seems to be the best way to access this data.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There was zero effort put into this question (esp since the OP came to the conclusion that `RCurl` is the current best practice for web wrangling in R) but anytime an SO web scraping question that involves a SharePoint site can actually be answered (Microsoft SharePoint is one of the worst things invented ever next to Windows) it's worth posting an answer.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)

# make an initial connection to get cookies
httr::GET(
  "http://www.railroadpm.org/home/RPM/Performance%20Reports/BNSF.aspx"
) -> res

# retrieve some hidden bits we need to pass b/c SharePoint is a wretched thing.
pg <- content(res, as = "parsed")
for_post <- html_nodes(pg, "input[type='hidden']")

# post the hidden form & save out the CSV
httr::POST(
  "http://www.railroadpm.org/home/RPM/Performance%20Reports/BNSF.aspx",
  body = as.list(
    c(
      setNames(
        html_attr(for_post, "value"),
        html_attr(for_post, "id")
      ),
      `__EVENTTARGET` = "ctl11$btnCSV"
    )
  ),
  write_disk("meaures.csv"),
  progress()
) -> res
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I actually did look around quite a bit for answers to this question and kept coming up short, hence the posting.  I try not to post on SO unless I am really struggling with a question.  Nevertheless, thank you very much.